# How do I set a condition to a linear fit in Python?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, curve-fitting

I have an arbitrarily defined set of points to which I want to fit to a linear relationship M = km+c where k is the slope and c is some constant. I also want to set the condition where 21(1-k)=c+5.

I've used both np.poly1d and sp.optimize.curve_fit to find values for k and c, both of which result in the same values, but I cannot find a way to apply the aforementioned condition.

This is the poly1d version:

```py
arbitrary_x=[17.1,17.5,18.9,20.5]
arbitrary_y=[6,7,10,14]
plt.scatter (arbitrary_x, arbitrary_y, color='r', marker='x')

dparallax_fit = np.polyfit(arbitrary_x, arbitrary_y, 1)
j = np.poly1d(dparallax_fit)

x_dparallax_fit = np.linspace(16, 22, 100)
y_dparallax_fit = j(x_dparallax_fit)
plt.plot(x_dparallax_fit, y_dparallax_fit, color='purple')
```

This is the sp.optimize.curve_fit option. As you will see, I attempted to assert the condition in the linear_fit function, but to no avail:

```py
m = np.linspace(16,22,100)

def find_lin_fit():
    #point and fit for the relationship between delta_parallax and d_max
    arbitrary_x=[17.1,17.5,18.9,20.5]
    arbitrary_y=[6,7,10,14]
    plt.scatter (arbitrary_x, arbitrary_y, color='r', marker='x')
    def linear_fit(m, k, c):
        #assert 21*(1-k)==c+5
        return k*m+c
    popt, pcov = sp.optimize.curve_fit(linear_fit, arbitrary_x, arbitrary_y)
    return popt, pcov

j = find_lin_fit()

plt.plot(m,j[0][0]*m+j[0][1], color='g')
```

Both result with a k=2.33, c=-33.88, but, again, I would like the condition of 21(1-k)=c+5 to be met even if the fit diverges a little from the actual line of best fit.

Also, feel free to point out any deviations from convention or redundancies in my code.

EDIT: 
To be more specific about what I mean by "diverge", I would like the line of fit to define the limit of the points in [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WVsaF.png) image. You'll be able to see the arbitrary points from above in this image marked with red x's. Using one of the values to find the other does not fit the limit accurately, and I still need the condition to be met for accuracy in later steps of my work. Essentially, I need the line to diverge a little in both parameters while maintaining an accurate representation of the limit of the data.

Comment: `...even if the fit diverges a little...` - Diverges in what way? Slope or offset? Both? Divergence criteria? Plug the value you found for  `k` or `c` into your condition and solve for the other,

Comment: @wwii I edited the post. Hopefully, it answers your questions.

Comment: The _aforementioned condition_ translates in `c = 16 - 21*k` hence you want to fit the function `M = k*m + 16 - 21*k`  → `(M-16) = k * (m-21)` hence for an _assigned_ translation of the axes you are looking for a line that is passing through the origin... that is possibly OK but I have to ask, is this what you are looking for?

Comment: @gboffi This seems like the simplest solution. Thank you!